# hoverformat only works with $ symbol, not other currencies?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm doing some plotting with `plot_ly` from `plotly` library.

I'm trying to use `S/`  currency, that is the symbol for the peruvian currency "nuevos soles".

Using hoverformat in layout to set the currency symbol only works for american dollars:

```
plot_ly(ha, x = ~periodo, y = ~precio.actual, color = ~ecommerce, 
        colors = c("#BED800", "#802D69", "#FF5500")) %>%
    add_boxplot() %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(
        hoverformat = '$,.2f'
    )) %>% 
    config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

But if I use the `S/`  symbol (notice the white space after the slash) the tooltip does not show any currency only the integer.

```
plot_ly(ha, x = ~periodo, y = ~precio.actual, color = ~ecommerce, 
            colors = c("#BED800", "#802D69", "#FF5500")) %>%
        add_boxplot() %>%
        layout(yaxis = list(
            hoverformat = 'S/ ,.2f'
        )) %>% 
        config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

**data:**

```
ha <- structure(list(periodo = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2017", 
"2016"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), ecommerce = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("falabella", "ripley", "linio"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), marca = c("samsung", "samsung", 
"lg", "lg", "samsung", "lg"), producto = c("samsung tv led hd 32'' 32j4000", 
"samsung smart tv led fhd 48\"\" 3d 48j6400", "lg smart tv led 43'' full hd 43lh5700", 
"lg smart tv led 49'' full hd 49lh5700", "samsung smart tv 50ju6500 led uhd 50\"\" - negro", 
"lg smart tv led 49\"\" ultra hd tv 49uh6500"), precio.antes = c(999, 
2799, 1649, 1999, 3699, 2799), precio.actual = c(799, 1999, 1249, 
1699, 2399, 2199), pulgadas = c(32, 48, 43, 49, 50, 49), rango = c("S/.500 -\r\n S/.1500", 
"S/.1500 -\r\n S/.2500", "S/.500 -\r\n S/.1500", "S/.1500 -\r\n S/.2500", 
"S/.1500 -\r\n S/.2500", "S/.1500 -\r\n S/.2500"), descuento = c(-0.2002002002002, 
-0.285816362986781, -0.242571255306246, -0.150075037518759, -0.351446336847797, 
-0.214362272240086)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: `$` is supposed to be a symbol for currency, not the actual dollar sign. Plotly uses d3's formatting language, https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format. Without using Javascript to modify the hoverinfo, I'd guess you are stuck.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters you're right. My Windows 10 is in English, I would need a way to show the peruvian symbol `S/` as the currency with Javascript I think, the problem is I don't know how.

Comment: https://plot.ly/r/locales/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `tickprefix` attribute instead of `hoverformat`:

```
plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~am, y = ~wt) %>%
  add_boxplot() %>%
  layout(yaxis = list( tickprefix = 'S/', tickformat = ',.2f' )) %>% 
  config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

This has the advantage of also showing up on the Y-axis ticks:

[image]

Comment: Does it use comma for thousends?

Comment: Thousands-separation is still controlled by `tickformat` so you can add `tickformat = ',.2f'` for that and it applies to both the axis and the hover.

Comment: I just edited my answer to show what that looks like

Comment: @OmarGonzales feel free to accept the answer if it meets your needs :)

Comment: ty. It was helpfull indeed.